# How to address children of a style ControlTemplate for animation?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, wpf-controls, datatrigger

I have a custom control extending a toggle button. This custom control has three dependency properties for `ImageSource`s that can be used to customize `Image`s that present a certain visual impression:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleFeedbackToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleFeedbackToggleButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="BtnGrid">
                    <Image x:Name="FeedbackImage" Source="{TemplateBinding FeedbackImageSource}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Source="{TemplateBinding NormalImageSource}" />
                    <Image x:Name="DisabledImage" Source="{TemplateBinding DisabledImageSource}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="DisabledImage"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" TargetName="BtnGrid"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="FeedbackImage"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FeedbackBlink, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SB_BlinkFeedback">
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1.0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SB_BlinkFeedback" />
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Another dependency property `FeedbackBlink` shall be used to start and stop blinking of only one of the images (`FeedbackImage`). Unfortunately I cannot find out how to address this image from the `Storyboard` "SB_BlinkFeedback". How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution shortly after posting the question: I had to move the `DataTrigger` from `<Style.Triggers>` to `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`. Then the `Storyboard` declaration can be completed by `Storyboard.TargetName="FeedbackImage"` without compiler or runtime error.